# Can I avoid NuGet removing Private (Copy Local) tag

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2017, nuget

Since our team upgraded from Visual Studio 2015 to Visual Studio 2017 we are having problems with NuGet packages. Everytime we update packages (no matter what feed) like e.g. MVC the update removes the "Private" tag in the project file:

```
<Reference Include="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.5.2.4\lib\net45\System.Web.Mvc.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

For me personally it doesn't really matter whether the assemblies are copied to any of the output directories. But it seems the Visual Studio itself is having problems with that because it hundreds of errors in the code editor, although compilation is completing successfully.

Is it possible to avoid NuGet Packet Manager to do so? Or ist there any other solution?

Comment: Have you the same behaviour with [PackageReference](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files) instead of old Reference on your NuGet package? In VS2017, i recommend to use PackageReference and remove packages.config in your project. You need to update ToolsVersion to 15.0

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think the hint to ToolsVersion did the trick. Anyway to complete my answer, we are still using packages.config. We didn't had anytime to plan migration to VS 2017 because an update to VS 2015 made the VS unusable. :-(

Answer (score 5):

> Is it possible to avoid NuGet Packet Manager to do so? Or ist there any other solution?

I am afraid there is no such way to resolve this issue. Because this is the default behavior for NuGet.

When we update the nuget package or re-install the nuget package, during the uninstall the  item is removed from the project file along with all its metadata (e.g., Private). During the install step, explicit Private metadata will only be added if it is needed. As such, `<Private>true</Private>` will be removed if the referenced assembly would have been copied locally anyway.

So, Visual Studio does copy the referenced assemblies to the bin directory on build, even though the  tag is removed from the project file. The Properties inspector on that assembly reference also shows that Visual Studio continues to interpret "Copy Local" as "True" even without that  tag.

Check [this thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/28961/vs2017-nuget-package-installationreinstall-resets.html) for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, this seems no to be quite correct. Because before upgrading to Visual Studio 2017 the Private-tag remained in the project file after updating NuGet Packages. And also the referenced assembly did not get copied locally before manually updating the tools version in the project file.